# Transparent faces on exported FBX

Tags: export, unity, unreal-engine

So I am trying to make a model, and in Blender 3D it looks fine, but when I export it to FBX and import it into Unity 3D or Unreal Editor 4 or any other 3D viewing software, you can see inside of it which makes it really ugly.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You have inverted normals. In edit mode, select all faces ("A"), then do "Ctrl+N". The object should turn from *blueish* to *greyish*, which means that your normals are now correctly pointing outwards.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I'm adding my comment as an answer. I had left it as a comment as I felt like it was a duplicate and I was going to mark it as such, but then I couldn't find an exact duplicate. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 3):

You have inverted normals.

In edit mode, select all faces (<kbd>A</kbd>), then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

The object should turn from *blueish* to *greyish*, which means that your normals are now correctly pointing outwards.