# Blender mirror error on objects

Tags: game-engine, mirror, error

When i export a object that i have mirrored it becomes transparent. when i undo the mirror effect it does not become transparent. does anyone know why this is happening?

[image: pics]
[image: after render]

Comment: How do you mirror it?.. Maybe apply scale to object in Blender, then recalculate normals. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63642/after-import-to-unity-all-my-normals-are-flipped/63649 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88898/transparent-faces-on-exported-fbx (search for recalculate normals shortcut for your version)

Comment: what do you mean by mirror? make sure that the normals are correctly flipped otherwise you won't see the face in the game engine, it may be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As moonboots already mentioned, it sounds like your problem's issue is that your mesh's polygons are flipped the wrong way. You can easily recalculate polygon normal directions by using the **[CTRL+N]** shortcut. If you wish to recalculate only selected polygons, select the desired polygons in edit-mode, than use the **[RMB]** shortcut to bring up the edit shortcut menu, then choose the **Mesh Tools -> Flip Normals** selection.

Some documentation.
https://all3dp.com/2/blender-recalculate-normals-simply-explained/

Comment: Yeah it fixed it,it flips the normals when i mirror a object